# Firefox or Chrome plugin to open Word Online files in LibreOffice on Linux?

Tags: linux, microsoft-word, libreoffice

So, I'm working on [Word Online](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-online/documents-spreadsheets-presentations-office-online), and I want to be able to open the .docx files in LibreOffice on Linux while still storing them in my OneDrive.

When I go to hit the "Open in Word" button, it tells me that I need a browser plugin to make it work. Of course, when I go to get the browser plugin, its a Windows executable, because Microsoft.

So, has someone hacked the system and written a plugin that will make this work, or do I need to do it myself?

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 (made for an i386 processor arch, which dates my computer a bit), with LibreOffice 5.0 and Firefox 40.0 + Canonical mods and Chromium 44.0.2403.89.

An equivalent question might be, is there a way to set up a OneDrive as a network drive or remote server on Linux?

Comment: You can map OneDrive as a network drive. See link for details: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/34847-onedrive-map-onedrive-pc-windows-8-1-a.html The link is for Windows mapping, you would just need to map the address in Linux

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj

I wouldn't say it's perfect, but it is very useful especially if you don't want to download the file even on windows computers